# Making my first bash script, can't get the cd command to 'stick.'

Tags: command-line, bash

For my first bash script, I want to create something that's really been annoying me: when I switch folders, I want the contents of that folder to be displated automatically. I tried adding this following code to ~/.bashrc:

```
alias go='cd; ls'
```

Simple enough I thought! Not so. While typing `go /etc` does indeed list the contents of /etc, my working directory hasn't actually changed, I'm still in the one I was in before. How do I remedy this?

Answer (score 29):

In your example, `go /etc` will do `cd; ls /etc`. That means, first, `cd` will change the current directory to your home directory. Then, `ls /etc` will display the contents of `/etc`.

You could achieve what you want by defining a function, like so:

```
function go() {
    cd "$1" && ls
}
```

Or just type it in the command line on a single line:

```
function go() { cd "$1" && ls; }
```

Then `go /etc` will do what you want.

`$1` refers to the first parameter passed to the command in this example `/etc`. You can refer to subsequent parameters with `$2`, `$3` and so on.

Comment: +1. One improvement: only execute `ls` if `cd` is successful: `go() { cd "$1" && ls; }` -- this avoids listing the current directory if the parameter does not exist.

Comment: This seems to have done the trick. While it doesn't look complicated relatively speaking, it turns out it was still a bit more complicated than I had initially intended. One quick question, though: how does the "$1" work?

Comment: @user3471004 - `$1` first argument passed to command - this also follows on with `$2` for the second, `$3` for the third, etc. `$@` can also be used to represents all of the arguments. Various examples can be found - e.g [this](http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_read_command_line_arguments_in_a_bash_script).

Answer (score -1):

You may want to combine this with the built-in bash directory stack (dirs).
this will give you the opportunity to type: `go ...`, to view the previous folder(s) in your stack, rather then type their name. an eg:

```
function go() { 
 if [ "$1" == "..." ]; then popd >/dev/null ; else pushd "$1" >/dev/null ; fi
 ls $@
}
```

you can substitute `...` with other keyword, like `_back`. something that wont be a directory name.

you will notice the `ls $@` which means all remaining parameters will be passed to ls. so if you want to go and have long listing, or reverse time listing, use:
`go /var -l` or 
`go /etc -ltr`

Comment: As you do not remove `$1` from `$@` it will still be the first argument for `ls $@`. In most cases this will lead to an error when using relative paths.

Comment: Not particularly relevant to the question.

Comment: The `$@` should be quoted in case any of the original terms contain spaces. Hence it should be `ls "$@"` (or with best practice `ls "${@}"`).